# Google Maps API for GPS like Navigation

Tags: google-maps

I am trying to use a navigation feature in my app that is being developed, both in iOS and Android. I used the following API

http://maps.google.com/?saddr=%f,%f&daddr=%f,%f

This api loads the google maps but it does not behave as a GPS navigation system where if the user misses an exit/street while driving, the navigation system redirects the user through an alternate route. The above API loads the google map URL into my app but the navigation button is missing.

Could someone help me with this issue.

I researched quite a bit on the forum but could not get an answer to my query. If this question has already been answered, kindly pardon me for raising this issue once again and I request you to point me to the right thread where this question is already answered.

Answer (score 0):

Google does not provide an API for this functionality as of yet and it's currently against their terms and conditions to attempt to provide turn by turn navigation to a mobile user.  The only option is to provide a link that opens the Google Navigate app with the destination specified.  On Android this is known as an intent.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have also written to Google Maps API sales team to check if there are any paid API's that I can use to implement the functionality. If there is one, I will add information on the same here for others' benefit. If there are any options for me for the iOS version, kindly let me know.

Comment: I have also offered to pay for this API, but they simply don't offer it on iOS or Android. Would be great if they did.